# Browser loading unrelated (non-existent) file when registering a service worker in an extension

Tags: javascript, browser, firefox-addon, service-worker, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm registering a service worker in an extension, but getting a TypeError because the browser is trying to load my service worker file as a path of the website *in addition* to my extension's file.
Registering like:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('swerk.js', {scope: '.'})
```

along with a then and catch for the promise in a main.js (and `swerk.js` is included in the manifest content_scripts).

In swerk.js, I just have a print to indicate when the worker is loaded.

When the extension is loaded and the service worker is registered, the print does succeed. However, the browser *also* attempts to load /swerk.js, which of course doesn't exist because I don't own the host and swerk.js is in my extension, so I get a TypeError:

```
extension loaded main.js:2:13
sworker loaded! swerk.js:1:9
Service worker registration failed:  TypeError: ServiceWorker script at <URL>/swerk.js for scope <URL> encountered an error during installation. main.js:8:21
```

and the promise's catch is called as expected because of the error. But why's <URL>/swerk.js being loaded?!

Using Firefox 109.0.

Comment: A service worker script must be on the domain's URL. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.